# How can I take only entries from even positions in List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How I can select using Linq only entries from even positions in a list ?

Comment: Even based on what; a row value, even in terms of the list in general, ...? You could `.Where(r => r.id % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) to Enumerable.Where in which the predicate includes the item's index.

```
var myList = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var evenIndexes = myList.Where( (num, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```